# Foreign key in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to convert the table that was dumped from mysql. Following is the code I have from mysql for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE "tbl_profession_attributes" (
"id" bigint(20) NOT NULL,
"tbl_profession_attribute_id" bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
"code" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
"name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
"keyword" text NOT NULL,
"tbl_profession_list_id" bigint(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
KEY "tbl_passion_attribute_id" ("tbl_profession_attribute_id"),
KEY "tbl_passion_list_id" ("tbl_profession_list_id")
);
```

When I run this query for sqlite, I get the following error:

```
Query Error: near "KEY": syntax error Unable to execute statement
```

Can someone please help me resolve this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, MySQL keyword `KEY` is synonym for `INDEX`. So this is not about  foreign key at all.

Second, SQLite does not support creating non-primary index in CREATE TABLE statement. You should specify separate statement for create index, something like:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_passion_attribute_id_idx
ON tbl_profession_attributes(tbl_profession_attribute_id)
```

Comment: +1 for the `INDEX` remark. I trusted the OP to know what the original code does ...